# Is it possible to create a tool tip, info tip or hint in GitHub markdown?

Tags: github, markdown

I have a markdown (MD) page on GitHub in a public repository that I want to add some additional information when someone clicks on a hyperlink. Ideally something similair to [Bootstrap's Popover](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#popovers).

Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: Your question is three years old. I just created a github pages site and I'm wondering if you are still using the accepted answer or something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly with GitHub page, which only support [GFM (GitHub Flavored Markdown Spec)](https://github.github.com/gfm/)

What you can do is use your GitHub repo with those mardown pages as sources for generating a static website (where you can add any additional information to the HTML code *you* are generating).
A [static website generator like Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) can help.
See "[Using a static site generator other than Jekyll](https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-static-site-generator-other-than-jekyll/)" for the process.

Comment: any reason for recommending Hugo over Jeckyll?

Comment: @TheEdge Easier to install (no dependencies, no ruby or any other runtime environment required), more features, and *vastly* faster: https://forestry.io/blog/hugo-vs-jekyll-benchmark/. Hugo has a tool to import a Jekyll site. https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/jekyll-ghpages-to-hugo-netlify/

Answer (score 27):

**Not exactly a [Bootstrap Popover](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#popovers) but** you can create **simple *"Tooltips"*** over links both here *(on StackOverflow)* and on GitHub, like so:

```markdown
[Hover your mouse here to see the tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71729464/11465149 "This is a tooltip :)")
```

[Hover your mouse here to see the tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71729464/11465149)

**Besides links**, on GitHub *(only)* you can also add **"tooltips" to plain text** like so:

```markdown
[id1]: ## "your hover text"
This is a [hover text][id1] example.
```

```markdown
This is a [hover text](## "your hover text") example.
```

<sup>[^ source](https://github.com/BoostIO/BoostNote-Legacy/issues/3579#issuecomment-855449583)</sup>

Comment: What if you do not want to set a link? Is the workaround using an anchor `#`? E. g. `[Hover you mouse here to see the tooltip](# "This is a tooltip :)")` ... seems not to work.

Comment: I didn't know "how to" either, I found about it and updated the answer just right now, thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: **Single `#` seems to work too, hmm..**

Comment: @GiorgosXou In GitHub: the single `#` creates a link that, when clicked, navigates the user to the top of the page. A double `##` creates a link that, when clicked, doesn't navigate the user anywhere.

(I'm referring to this syntax: `This is a [hover text](## "your hover text") example.`)

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly. Surely this isn't web browser native... Chromium Android Mobile doesn't show the hover text. Could you post another answer in the feed for archived reference.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).